# Trying to find shortest sentence in string using arrays

Tags: c++, c-strings, minimum, strlen

I got function to find longest sentence in array of sentences how can i now turn this to find the shortest and then copy that into char R[red]; and then manipulate over last word of the sentence of the shortests one to change first and last letter into uppercase

```
void longest (char SENTENCE[max][red],char R[red], int n){
    int longest = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
        if(strlen(SENTENCE[i]) > longest){
            longest = strlen(SENTENCE[i]);
            strcpy_s(R,red,SENTENCE[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which specific part of this question is unclear to you? Shouldn't it be obvious, `<` instead of `>`, and initialize `longest` to the length of the first array (after checking, of course, that `n` is at least 1)?

Comment: are you trying to use C or C++ ?

Comment: I am trying to use c++

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

For starters there is the standard algorithm `std::min_element` that returns an iterator that points to the minimal element in a container. However using it with the function strlen will not be very efficient.

So you can indeed write such a function yourself. It can look the following way

```
void shortest( const char s[][red], char t[], size_t n )
{
    t[0] = '\0';

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        size_t min_i   = 0;
        size_t min_len = std::strlen( s[0] );

        for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
        {
            size_t len = std::strlen( s[i] );
            if ( len < min_len )
            {
                min_i   = i;
                min_len = len;
            }
        }

        std::strcpy( t, s[min_i] ); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Made it this way

```
void shortest (char SENTENCE[max][red],char R[red], int n){
    int shortest = strlen(SENTENCE[0]);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
        if(strlen(SENTENCE[i]) < shortest){
            shortest = strlen(SENTENCE[i]);
            strcpy_s(R,red,SENTENCE[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This function implementation in general case is invalid and inefficient because there are redundant calls of strlen and strcpy.